# Rhomobile asynchttp multiple calls

Tags: rhomobile

Hi I am stuck using the webinars on rhomobile.com: 'Using AsyncHttp to load data from JSON'. I followed the example and its working fine. The only problem i have is everytime AsyncHttp  is called the same products are parse repeatedly. Is there a way to call AsyncHttp  without reapeating these outputs?. Sample code will be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hmm... you make a request to the same url repeatedly and get back the same results?  Sounds like it's working to me.

If you want different results, you need to request from a different url, or more simply (if you're using that products example), you'll need to add or edit some product records.

The url seems to be open (http://rhostore.heroku.com/products), so you can just navigate to that page and simple create some new products using that web application.